# Why isn't my Chrome App in kiosk mode automatically updating?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome app that runs on a few dozen devices in auto-boot kiosk mode.

I've pushed several updates to the web store, and while I do see the update on my local Chromebox after a little bit of waiting, I've come to learn that the many devices running it in kiosk mode are on an array of older versions. Some seem to have updated at some point in time, but many have not, and none are on the latest version that's already several days old.

Is this because they are in kiosk mode? I found [this question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-education/school-administrators/chrome-and-chromebooks/chrome-browser/report-an-issue/laxMLfFcf5k) over on the product forums, but it has no answer. Seems like the behavior I'm experiencing, and if so I could see why this is the case. Still, all of the documentation from Google pertaining to apps suggests they should always be auto-updating themselves.

Comment: Did you ever get any clarity on this? Seeing the same issues -- auto update of apps seems to be hit or miss ... and I haven't found any clear guidance as to how (and with what timing) it's actually supposed to work. Frustrating.

Comment: @BenRoberts It's been a while since this has come up because the current version they're using is stable. I believe that in kiosk mode – even with a restart – they wouldn't upgrade themselves. When we've needed to update them, I've had to manually interrupt the kiosk boot, log in, open the extensions tab and wait a few minutes for them to update, then restart the device. (or something along those lines). Best of luck!

Comment: We're having this same exact issue. I have ~40 Chromebit devices that are running an app in kiosk mode. It NEVER updates the application from the Chrome Web Store. The only work around we've been able to determine is to remove the app from the devices OU in Gsuite Management Console and then add it back. Effectively an uninstall - reinstall. Not ideal.

Comment: @AndreLackmann you're not able to interrupt the kiosk startup by logging in and then visiting the extensions page to update?

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser you can do this - but the app launched in single app kiosk mode is it's own installation and doesn't get updated by this method. We did find a solution to this however, so I'll post one below.

Answer (score 2):

We had this same issue and luckily have a support agreement with Google. After some log searching, we were able to determine that the kiosk app we were deploying was specifying a kiosk `required_platform_version`, eg.

```
"kiosk": {
    "required_platform_version": "11021.56.0"
},
```

While our Chrome devices (ASUS Chromebit in this case) were already beyond the required version specified. As Chrome won't downgrade itself, the new version in the Chrome Web Store is deemed ineligible for this device and upgrades are never applied.

To resolve this issue, we posted a new version of our Kiosk app with this value updated to match the currently highest deployed Chrome platform version in our fleet (you could also just remove it - but for long running Kiosk apps it's best practice to lock the Chrome version).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/r8pl03AWkZk) which states the following:

> If these are school managed chromebooks, see this [topic](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/jbg5YEM5A4M).
>
> If it is not managed or if the settings have not been changed in the management console, the chromebook does have to be restarted to finish updating.
>
> https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en

Simply follow the given steps on how to manage kiosk settings.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and share this. A restart doesn't impact the state of the extensions for me. It seems that in auto-boot kiosk mode, where the user doesn't log in, the system and extensions just don't update.